# FQL query to graph api v2.0 transform

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to transform a function from FQL to Graph API v2.0.But i have a very little knowledge in Graph API v2.0 .The function is-

```
            function check_page($id){
            global $facebook;
            try {
                $param = array(
                    'method'   => 'fql.query',
                    'query'    => "SELECT like_info FROM photo WHERE object_id='".$id."'",
                    'callback' => ''
                );
                $response = $facebook->api($param);
                $likes = $response[0]['like_info']['like_count'];
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $url = get_data('https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+like_info+FROM+photo+WHERE+object_id='.$id);
                $result = json_decode($url, true);
                $likes = $result['data'][0]['like_info']['like_count'];
            }
            if(is_numeric($likes) && $likes >= 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

So Graph API experts i need your help to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently FQL can give you 3 fields, i.e. **can_like**, **like_count**, and **user_likes**

[image]

The **/photo_object_ID** connection equivalent to this FQL is

> {OBJECT_ID OR POST_ID}/likes?summary=true&limit=0

[image]

Currently there's no "can_like" and "user_likes" replacement to FQL.

I filed a feature request at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1468637860040091/ and kindly subscibe it.

Comment: That means its impossible to transform the above code?

Comment: @pegasus Based on your app requirement, if you only need like_count(total of like of this post) data, then you shoud able transform the above code.  "can_like" means current user have the permission to like the post or not. And "user_likes" is means current user already like the post or not.

Comment: If i need only like_info then please tell me how will i write it?

Comment: Please check this documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/